# Generating XML based on dataset class created by XSD.exe

Tags: c#, class, dataset, xsd.exe

Could anyone give an overview of how to generate an XML from the dataset class of an XML schema created using XSD.exe?

I have previously worked using C# class generated for a schema from XSD.exe, where I used the serialisation to finally create my output XML, but have no clues how to work with the dataset class.

Can anyone please give your ideas on this?? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

MSDN article describes serializing a DataSet to XML.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your time!! The above link just explains serializing a dataset, I want the explanation with regard to the typed dataset created using XSD.exe